# Could one user updates while other users cannot select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way in MySQL and PHP to allow only the person performing an update to view information about a particular record?

For example, if one user loads the page they are presented with a record which must be updated, until that user finishes updating this record, any other user accessing this page should not be able to view this particular record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either add a field named like `locked` where you set a status. Maybe you also add a field like `lockedtime` where you save a timestamp how long the lock is active. That depends on your needs.

There are also possibilities to do this native. Like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE primarykey = x FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` requires InnoDB tables and works only within transaction scope - there is no way that two independent PHP script executions share the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

add a "locked" column to the table, and once a user calls the edit form, set the "locked" db value to the user_id, and after save set it back to false/null.
In your view action, check the locked value

Comment: and how is he going to know whether row was locked by requesting user or other user?

Comment: Correct, locked field should have the user_id

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually lock the row (by adding a `IsLocked` column) when someone requests the edit page, since the connection to the database is lost as soon as the PHP script execution ends (despite pooling et al, script execution is stopped so you cannot unlock from the same thread again since that connection may go to another script).

Don't forget to create a kind of unlocking script, initiated by cron for example, to unlock rows that have been locked for more than a given amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend adding any column to data table in question. I'd rather create special `locks` table to hold the information:

```
create table locks (
    tablename varchar,
    primarykey int,
    userid int,
    locktime datetime);
```

Then take the following principles into consideration:

- each PHP request is a standalone mysql connection, that's why solutions like `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` won't work and that's why you need to keep userid of a person - who actually did first request and performed the lock
- every access to `locks` table must lock the table as a whole (using MySQL's `LOCK` statement) to avoid concurrency in locking the same row
- if there is no way to know, whether particular uses has abandoned editing the row by closing the window with record - then either `locktime` timeout must be short or you should provide some *ping* (i.e. AJAX) mechanism that would reset `locktime` as long as user is working on locked record
- user can save changes to record as long as he/she owns the lock and `locktime` did not expire
- `tablename` and `primarykey` are of course samples and you should adjust them to your needs :-)